# springboot vue Whitelabel Error Page only by refreshing

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security

there are many questions about this topic, but i ve only problems with reloading pages:[reload a vuejs page (e.g. F5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWMkO.png)

when the page is reloaded, this url is called up (but is a vue-page): GET https://localhost:8444/company 404

i found this example but is not working for me (because this controller is not called):

```
// Forwards all routes to FrontEnd except: '/', '/index.html', '/api', '/api/**'
    // Required because of 'mode: history' usage in frontend routing, see README for
    // further details
    @RequestMapping(value = "{_:^(?!index\\.html|api).*$}")
    public String redirectApi() {
        logger.info("URL entered directly into the Browser, so we need to redirect...");
        return "forward:/";
    }
```

last class it goes through is this filterclass:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Secure Conf:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
//          .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
```

Project Structure: [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhxjL.png)

I am new in Springboot / VUE ... i hope someone can help me